# Excel error 1004: Copy area and paste area aren't the same size

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to copy data from many spreadsheets into one sheet. I am copying from ranges A:L, and when the data is pasted from A:L on the summary sheet, it works with no issues. I am trying to paste my data on columns B:M, which is when I receive the 1004 error. I have a slightly modified code from the MSDN site:

I receive the error when I change the `With DestSh.Cells(Last + 1, "A")` to `With DestSh.Cells(Last + 1, "B")`

```
 ' Loop through all worksheets and copy the data to the
    ' summary worksheet.
    For Each sh In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        If sh.Name <> DestSh.Name And sh.Name <> "Pivot Table" And sh.Name <> "Combined" Then

            ' Find the last row with data on the summary
            ' and source worksheets.
            Last = LastRow(DestSh)
            shLast = FindLastRow(sh)

            ' If source worksheet is not empty and if the last
            ' row >= StartRow, copy the range.
            If shLast > 0 And shLast >= StartRow Then
                'Set the range that you want to copy
                Set CopyRng = sh.Range(sh.Rows(StartRow), sh.Rows(shLast))
                StartRow = 2

               ' Test to see whether there are enough rows in the summary
               ' worksheet to copy all the data.
                If Last + CopyRng.Rows.Count > DestSh.Rows.Count Then
                   MsgBox "There are not enough rows in the " & _
                   "summary worksheet to place the data."
                   GoTo ExitTheSub
                End If

                ' This statement copies values and formats.
                CopyRng.Copy
                With DestSh.Cells(Last + 1, "A")
                    .PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
                    Application.CutCopyMode = False
                End With

            End If

        End If
    Next
```

Comment: What is the *Address* of `CopyRng`?

Comment: Doe either worksheet, specifically in the range that is being copied (or destination) contain Merged Cells?

Comment: Just curious - do you get the error using `With DestSh.Cells(Last + 1, 2)`?  Also, is `Last` a `Long` or `Integer`?

Comment: Try setting your copy range as `Set CopyRng = Intersect(sh.UsedRange, sh.Range(sh.Rows(StartRow), sh.Rows(shLast)))`.

Comment: Also, what's the difference between your two functions `LastRow` and `FindLastRow` -- that could be a problem, but you haven't show us those implementations...

Comment: @DavidZemens no merged cells exist. 'LastRow' it uses 'Find', which will counts a summary row that I do not want included in the summary sheet. 'FindLastRow' uses 'sh.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row' to skip that summary row.

Comment: check the address of the `CopyRng` please

Comment: @Domenic That worked! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

From Domenic:

Try setting your copy range as:

Set CopyRng = Intersect(sh.UsedRange, sh.Range(sh.Rows(StartRow), sh.Rows(shLast)))

Solution:

```
        If shLast > 0 And shLast >= StartRow Then
            'Set the range that you want to copy
            'Set CopyRng = sh.Range(sh.Rows(StartRow), sh.Rows(shLast))
            'StartRow = 2

            Set CopyRng = Intersect(sh.UsedRange, sh.Range(sh.Rows(StartRow), sh.Rows(shLast)))
```